# jQuery dataTables wrong sorting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with jQuery dataTable sorting. It sorts columns in wrong order. For example: I have numbers from 1 to 5, when I click to sort that column it sorts in random order: 4, 1, 3, 5, 2. It's not only with number type. String, date - same problem. I have my data in MySQL database and I get it in json format. My datatable code:

```js
var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
        url:"data_control/orders/fetch.php",
        type:"POST"
    },
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        paint();
    },
    columnDefs: [
        { 
            "orderable": false, 
            targets: [11, 12, 13, 14]
        }
    ]
});
```

As I already mentioned - I select my data from database in fetch.php file in JSON format. Any ideas how to solve my problem with sorting?
Thanks!

Comment: `Datatable`,  with the data from the server, it will sort the data at the server

Comment: I made new function on server side. When I click sort, I get column name, direction (asc or desc) and in this way I add for example "order by id desc" in the end of query, in this way my table refreshes with new order, but order still random. I think that my data is in wrong order in my array where I push all data from database.

Comment: you need to check the returned data on the server side, the datatable side only displays the data

Comment: Because you are using `"serverSide" : true`, all sorting (and filtering and paging) needs to be handled by the server. But you have only shown us some client-side code. None of that code controls sorting. Show us the relevant server-side sorting code, together with the results sent from the server to the client. (Also, do you actually want/need `"serverSide" : true`? You can fetch data via Ajax without using that option - and then you can use DataTables built-in sorting.)